# Hide Nav bar items during search

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 nav bar items in my `navigationBar` like so:

```
func setupNavBarButtons() {
    let searchImage = UIImage(named: "search_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))

    let mapBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Map", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(displayMap))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [mapBarButtonItem , searchBarButtonItem]

    let filterBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filter", style: .Plain , target: self, action: #selector(displayFilter))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = filterBarButtonItem
}
```

When I tap the search icon it calls the function below:

```
func handleSearch() {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar        
}
```

I want to hide all `navigationBarItems` while user is searching and then return nav bar items once user is done searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this in your `handleSearch` method remove the left and right bar button item, After that on `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method of `UISearchBarDelegate` you can set it again that bar items.

```
func handleSearch() {
    searchController.searchBar.hidden = false
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.setupNavBarButtons()
    searchController.searchBar.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: How can I make it possible to make the user start typing instantly rather than clicking the search icon then clicking the search bar to type?